# how to send an XML request to an API with R

Tags: xml, r, curl

i am trying to automate the download of a bit of data from the API of [this government website](http://finder.healthcare.gov/services/version_2_0).

the website instructs:

```
All requests for this version should be made to the following URL:
http://api.finder.healthcare.gov/v2.0/
```

i can find plenty of information about how to send xml requests, but none of the examples are `R`-specific..  and there's plenty of R code out there that shows how to use the `XML`, `httr`, and `RCurl` packages, but i couldn't find any examples on SO or the r-help mailing list of how to actually *send* an xml request.  ..there's more documentation for parsing the response.

on [the government website](http://finder.healthcare.gov/services/version_2_0), if you click the `PlansForIndividualOrFamily Samples` example, it displays the xml request (code below) that needs to be sent.

```
url <- "http://api.finder.healthcare.gov/v2.0/"

xml.request <-
    "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
    <PrivateOptionsAPIRequest>
        <PlansForIndividualOrFamilyRequest>
            <Enrollees>
                <Primary>
                    <DateOfBirth>1990-01-01</DateOfBirth>
                    <Gender>Male</Gender>
                    <TobaccoUser>Smoker</TobaccoUser>
                </Primary>
            </Enrollees>
            <Location>
                <ZipCode>69201</ZipCode>
                <County>
                    <CountyName>CHERRY</CountyName>
                    <StateCode>NE</StateCode>
                </County>
            </Location>
            <InsuranceEffectiveDate>2012-10-01</InsuranceEffectiveDate>
        <IsFilterAnalysisRequiredIndicator>false</IsFilterAnalysisRequiredIndicator>
        <PaginationInformation>
            <PageNumber>1</PageNumber>
            <PageSize>10</PageSize>
        </PaginationInformation>
        <SortOrder>
            <SortField>OOP LIMIT - INDIVIDUAL - IN NETWORK</SortField>
            <SortDirection>ASC</SortDirection>
        </SortOrder>
        <Filter/>
        </PlansForIndividualOrFamilyRequest>
    </PrivateOptionsAPIRequest>"
```

Comment: do you happen to know how you can send xml requests to http://api.finder.healthcare.gov/v2.0/ ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using `RCurl` you do this ;

```
myheader=c(Connection="close", 
            'Content-Type' = "application/xml",
             'Content-length' =nchar(xml.request))
data =  getURL(url = url,
                    postfields=xml.request,
                    httpheader=myheader,
                    verbose=TRUE)
```

That's about it. Then You can using `xpathApply` of XML package to retrieve data. For example to get families ID:

```
library(XML)
xmltext  <- xmlTreeParse(data, asText = TRUE,useInternalNodes=T)
 unlist(xpathApply(xmltext,'//Plan/PlanID',xmlValue))  ## change the right xpath here

 "29678NE0780012" "29678NE0780011" "29678NE0140010"  
  "29678NE0780010" "29678NE0140019" "29678NE0140018" "29678NE0140017"
  "29678NE0140016" "29678NE0780005" "29678NE0780004"
```