# How to submit XML to Web Service using R

Tags: r, xml, web-services

I have a Web Service that I need to call through R.  The Web Service demands data in a particular format.  Below are the details for the Web Service that I received from the IT department and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15240408/how-to-send-an-xml-request-to-an-api-with-r) is the closest forum I could find related to my problem.  But the answer given in the link is too cryptic for a novice like me.  I have already tried playing with the given code without any success.

Web Service Details

The below XML is what needs to be sent through R.

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:sch="http://www.xxxxx.com/xxxxservice/schema">
   <S:Header/>
   <S:Body>
      <sch:OwnerOnlyInquiryRequest>
         <sch:RequestHeader>
            <sch:ClientSystem>CESE</sch:ClientSystem>
         </sch:RequestHeader>
         <sch:RequestParameterList>
            <sch:RequestParam>8905899</sch:RequestParam>
         </sch:RequestParameterList>
         <sch:RequestType>CESEID</sch:RequestType>
         <sch:PeckingOrder>Pricing</sch:PeckingOrder>
         <sch:ViewType>Pricing</sch:ViewType>
      </sch:OwnerOnlyInquiryRequest>
   </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

All I know is that it should be a POST request.  And some other details are

With the post information:

```
POST http://slsesotdevtcl1.ute.xxxx.com:10149/xxx/xxxservice.wsdl HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
SOAPAction: ""
Content-Length: 637
Host: slsesotdevtcl1.ute.xxxxx.com:10149
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)
```

I could find many forums where the question surrounds on how to read/parse the xml response received in R.  I am struggling a step behind this, since I first need to figure out how to send the request.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: See [pages 30-31](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/httr/httr.pdf) of the `httr` package for how to use POST.

Comment: It does not tell me anything about XML.  In encoding, I believe there needs to be an option for XML?  I am not sure.

Comment: @hrbrmstr.  You are right!  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26717706/soap-request-in-r give s the solution I was looking for.  Many many thanks!